# How to retrieve json encoded data after an Ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using an ajax post to submit data for validation and storing in a database. If the data fails server-side validation error messages are then json encoded and sent back like this:

```
$errorArray = array();
        if (!empty($nameErr)) {

            $errorArray["nameErr"] = $nameErr;
        }
        if (!empty($emailErr)) {

            $errorArray["emailErr"] = $emailErr;
        }
        if (!empty($phoneErr)) {

            $errorArray["phoneErr"] = $phoneErr;
        }
        if (!empty($commentErr)) {

            $errorArray["commentErr"] = $commentErr;
        }

        $data = json_encode($errorArray);
        echo $data;
```

Then in the success callback of my ajax post I will displayt these errors, my question is how do I access these messages that are sent in the json encode function?

I have tried

```
error.response['nameErr']
```

and

```
error.response('errorArray["nameErr"])
```

but neither seem to work?

Comment: are you using jquery for the ajax call?

Comment: We need your JS code, and the meaning of `neither seem to work`

Comment: assuming you are sending correct content type header from your PHP script, the `success` callback function's first argument will contain the expected data.

Comment: is your `dataType` set to `json`? If not use `jQuery.parseJSON` on the return object and you can access it as `response.nameErr`

Comment: I am using jquery and cannot set to the dataType to json because then it doesnt run the success callback

Comment: user3050033 - check out my answer, regardless of you saying "datattype" cannot be set, my example will work. Give it a try :)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to have a header declaration in your PHP so that returning text is read as json.

In this case, you also need to set your ajax data type as json so it is prepared to receive json.

The success function of your ajax request simply does an if statement and if `data.Error` is false, you've got a problem and you can go ahead and read the `data.ErrorMessage` you yourself have recorded server side.

**JavaScript:**

```
var requestObject = { Property1 = "Hi" };

$.ajax({
   url: myUrl,
   method: "post",
   data: requestObject,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function( data )
   {
      if( data.Error )
      {
         HandleError( data.ErrorMessage );
      }       
      else
      {
         // Do stuff with data.Response
      }
   }
   error: function( e )
   {
      alert( JSON.stringify( e ) ); // This usually relates to server side errors, 404 not founds etc... so this function will not magically know that your validation failed... Although you could perhaps throw a PHP fatal error... 
   }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
   if( $_POST[ "Property1" ] != "sausage" )
   {
      header('Content-Type: application/json'); // This line will make your ajax be okay with the json response
      $response = array(
         "Error" => TRUE,
         "ErrorMessage" => array( "Hey that doesn't equal sausage" ),
         "Response" => false
      );
      echo json_encode( $response );
   }
```

In your case, have an array of errors and fill them up as bits are not correctly passed... for example:

```
$errors = array();

if( /* condition */ )
    $errors[] = "Error message 1";
if( /* condition */ )
    $errors[] = "Error message 2";

if( count( $errors ) > 0 )


$response = array(
    "Error" => TRUE,
    "ErrorMessage" => $errors,
    "Response" => false // Nothing to send back because there were errors
);

echo json_encode( $response );
```

**P.S**

If you're having issues getting the error messages or response you desire. Don't forget to check out the network tab in your favourite Developer Toolbar... Mines IE11 so here's an example of that:

[image]

Comment: No explanation, no relation with OP's code. How is this helpful?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger - I was still typing my answer when you posted this (you have to be patient). The answer is a complete solution to the OPs problem.

Comment: Okay so after saying that things wouldnt work if I changed the data type to json I changed it to json and I can now use the errors I json encoded in my success callback!! :) I think Im missing something very important about the whole dataType of the ajax post, because now even though I can use that data that was sent through, I now can't change the text value of the success label ??!! And if I take out the  dataType:json the exact same code to change the label works, but using the error messages doesnt !! Quite confused I must say

Comment: can you update your OP to show your javascript and php... similar to what I have done above?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you mean to parse json in javascript.

For that you need to do:

```
JSON.parse('json');
```

Or

If you are using jquery, you can also do:

```
$.parseJSON('json');
```

Both will return you objects parsed from JSON.

Comment: So in my ajax success callback, I could say:

Comment: var errorArray = $.parseJSON('json') and then access the error messages through errorArray.errorArray['nameErr']     ?

Comment: Hmm still doesnt seem to work, when I try it I get a syntax error in my jquery: "Unexpected token r"

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple json all:

```
$.getJSON("serverpage.php", { form_data })
    .done(function (data) {
          console.log(data);

          });
    })
    .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log(error);
});
```